# Application Authentication to Azure without using Service Principal

Tags: java, c#, powershell, azure, authentication

I am designing a generic tool (like a dashboard) which "fetches" data from Azure subscription and displays. The purpose of this tool is to be used by anyone. Authentication should be through their Azure credentials [ID and Password]. Similar when we login to "portal.azure.com".

However, we know that any application that wants to authenticate to Azure has to have Service Principal, which defeats the purpose of the application being "generic", i.e., the user is forced to use "Service Principal".

So, my question, is there any way we can authenticate an application to Azure just using Azure credentials [like we do it in Powershell's Login-AzureRMAccount cmdlet]

Comment: Please refer to the document [Use Resource Manager authentication API to access subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-api-authentication) and try to register a native app to use code grant flow for authentication.

Comment: You could use AzureAD Module and connect to the Azure tenant using -  Connect-AzureAD -AzureEnvironmentName -TenantId -Credential